# optimal way of storing multidimensional array/tensor

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a tensor (can be conceived as a multidimensional array) package in `scala`. So far I was storing the data in a 1D `Vector` and doing index arithmetic.

But slicing and subarrays are not so easy to get. One needs to do a lot of arithmetic to convert multidimensional indices to 1D indices.

Is there any optimal way of storing a multidimensional array? If not, i.e. 1D array is the best solution, how one can optimally slice arrays (some concrete code would really help me)?

Comment: +1 wondering if there is a mathematical modelling API for Scala. Then I wonder, may be you can use a Java API for mathematical modelling that probably abstracts you from dealing with minute details of doing trivial tasks with tensor and let you focus on logic.

Comment: @Nishant: for linear algebra there is scalala: https://github.com/scalala/Scalala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to answering this question is: when is pointer indirection faster than arithmetic?  The answer is pretty much never.  In-order traversals can be about equally fast for 2D, and things get worse from there:

```
2D random access
  Array of Arrays - 600 M / second
  Multiplication - 1.1 G / second

3D in-order
  Array of Array of Arrays - 2.4G / second
  Multiplication - 2.8 G / second

(etc.)
```

So you're better off just doing the math.

Now the question is how to do slicing.  Initially, if you have dimensions of n1, n2, n3, ... and indices of i1, i2, i3, ..., you compute the offset into the array by

```
i = i1 + n1*(i2 + n2*(i3 + ... ))
```

where typically `i1` is chosen to be the *last* (innermost) dimension (but in general it should be the dimension most often in the innermost loop).  That is, if it were an array of arrays of (...), you would index into it as `a(...)(i3)(i2)(i1)`.

Now suppose you want to slice this.  First, you might give an offset o1, o2, o3 to every index:

```
i = (i1 + o1) + n1*((i2 + o2) + n2*((i3 + o3) + ...))
```

and then you will have a shorter range on each (let's call these m1, m2, m3, ...).

Finally, if you eliminate a dimension entirely--let's say, for example, that `m2 == 1`, meaning that `i2 == 0`, you just simplify the formula:

```
i = (i1 + o1 + n1*o2) + (n1+n2)*((i3 + o3) + ... ))
```

I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out how to do this in general, but note that we can store new constants `o1 + n1*o21` and `n1+n2` so we don't need to keep doing that math on the slice.

Finally, if you are allowing arbitrary dimensions, you just put that math into a while loop.  This does, admittedly, slow it down a little bit, but you're still at least as well off as if you'd used a pointer dereference (in almost every case).

Answer (score 1):

From my own general experience: If you have to write a multidimensional (rectangular) array class yourself, do not aim to store the data as `Array[Array[Double]]` but use a one-dimensional storage and add helper methods for converting the multidimensional access tuples to a simple index and vice versa.

When using lists of lists, you need to do much to much bookkeeping that all lists are of the same size and you need to be careful when assigning a sublist to another sublist (because this makes the assigned to sublist identical to the first and you wonder why changing the item at `(0,5)` also changes `(3,5)`).

Of course, if you expect a certain dimension to be sliced much more often than another and you want to have reference semantics for that dimension as well, a list of lists will be the better solution, as you may pass around those inner lists as a slice to the consumer without making any copy. But if you don’t expect that, it is a better solution to add a proxy class for the slices which maps to the multidimensional array (which in turn maps to the one-dimensional storage array).

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: how about a map with Int-tuples as keys?
Example:

```
val twoDimMatrix = Map((1,1) -> -1, (1,2) -> 5, (2,1) -> 7.7, (2,2) -> 9)
```

and then you could

```
scala> twoDimMatrix.filterKeys{_._2 == 1}.values 
res1: Iterable[AnyVal] = MapLike(-1, 7.7)
```

or

```
twoDimMatrix.filterKeys{tuple => { val (dim1, dim2) = tuple; dim1 == dim2}} //diagonal
```

this way the index arithmetics would be done by the map. I don't know how practical and fast this is though.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the number of dimension is known before the design, you can use a collection of collection ...(n times) of collection. If you must be able to build a verctor for any number of dimension, then, there's nothing convenient in the scala API to do it (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store information in a mulitdimensional array (*eg*. `Array[Array[Double]]).

If the tensors are small and can fit in cache, you can have a performance improvement with 1D arrays because of data memory locality. It should also be faster to copy the whole tensor.

For slicing arithmetic. It depends what kind of slicing you require. I suppose you already have a function for extracting an element based on indices. So write a basic splicing loop based on indices iteration, insert manually the expression for extracting element, and then try to simplify the whole loop. It is often simpler than to write a correct expression from scratch.